# How do you set a cookie under a different sub-domain in JSP?

Tags: jsp, cookies

Cookies are stored under a domain-name.
For example, a cookie that's generated by **sub1.example.com/login.jsp** can be stored in **sub1.example.com**, or **example.com**.

Can I store the cookie in **sub2.example.com**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the cookie a domain name of `.example.com` (note the leading dot). This way the cookie is accessible by **any** subdomain. If you intend to share the `HttpSession` among subdomains, then you can also just configure the appserver to do so. Best is to refer its documentation for details. In case of for example Tomcat, just set the `emptySessionPath` attribute of the [`<Connector>`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html) to `true`:

```
<Connector emptySessionPath="true">
```